# Bootstrap's grid: elements with different heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on an application that dynamicaly adds elements to the DOM. The added elements are of two types: ones with height 50px and ones with 100px. They are displayed in with the help of the bootstrap grid system.

Working example:

```
<div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 100px;">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px;">2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px;">3</div>
</div>
```

But when i try to rearrange, some unexpected spaces occur on certain layouts:

```
<div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px;">2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 100px;">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px;">3</div>
</div>
```

Between element '1' and '3' there is a 50px wide gap. Is there any arrangement where the element '3' is placed in that gap?
Why is this gap occuring?

Comment: If I understood bootstrap correctly, all columns in a row should add up to 12 (not that it would fix your problem, but I think it's best practice)

Comment: @knittl You are correct; secondly if they are in a `row` they would have an extra-padding & margin (thus overflowing), which the `container` div would cancel out

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the columns exceeding 12 in a single row. This is what makes the Bootstrap grid so flexible on mobile devices: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gaurav is correct.. it's happening because you have specific `height` set. When the `height:100px` col is placed 2nd it forces #3 to wrap to a new row since the Bootstrap colums float left, but do not float right.

A workaround would be to use the `pull-right` class on the taller (100px) column...

http://bootply.com/129818

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have added inline style for height.

```
style="height: 100px;
style="height: 50px;
style="height: 50px;
```

To know it better look the example here
[jsfiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/kh3dJ/)
[jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/kh3dJ/1/)